# Nokogiri parsing a datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I am doing a scraping in a website and get stucked on this:

```
inside_doc.css('.listing-header-container').at_css("h3 time").to_s

 => "<time datetime=\"2018-08-10T16:49:03Z\" data-local=\"time\" data-format=\"%b %e\">Aug 10</time>"
```

Im trying to get this 'datetime'element to add to my model. In this case I want to get this value:

```
2018-08-10T16:49:03Z\
```

In my model I have a attribute called:

```
@my_model.date_of_publication = 2018-08-10T16:49:03Z\
```

How can I do this in Nokogiri?

Answer (score 0):

I just found. Just add a @datetime to the parsing

inside_doc.css('.listing-header-container').at_css("h3 time @datetime").to_s

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
dt = page.at('time[datetime]')['datetime']
```

and then you can parse that with Chronic:

```
time = Chronic.parse dt
```